# Python subprocesses with several pipes

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I know how to do several "nested" pipes using subprocesses however I have another doubt. I want to do the following:

```
p1=Popen(cmd1,stdout=PIPE)
p2=Popen(cmd2,stdin=p1.stdout)
p3=Popen(cmd3,stdin=p1.stdout)
```

Take into account that p3 uses p1.stdout instead of p2.stdout. The problem is that after doing p2, p1.stdout is blank. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send the same pipe to two different processes. Or, rather, if you do, they end up accessing the same pipe, meaning if one process reads something, it's no longer available to the other one.

What you need to do is "tee" the data in some way.

---

If you don't need to stream the data as they come in, you can read all the output from `p1`, then send it as input to both `p2` and `p3`. This is easy:

```
output = check_output(cmd1)
p2 = Popen(cmd2, stdin=PIPE)
p2.communicate(output)
p3 = Popen(cmd3, stdin=PIPE)
p3.communicate(output)
```

---

If you just need `p2` and `p3` to run in parallel, you can just run them each in a thread.

But if you actually need real-time streaming, you have to connect things up more carefully. If you can be sure that `p2` and `p3` will always consume their input, without blocking, faster than `p1` can supply it, you can do this without threads (just loop on `p1.stdout.read()`), but otherwise, you'll need an output thread for each consumer process, and a `Queue` or some other way to pass the data around. See the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/82aab9b1066d/Lib/subprocess.py) to `communicate` for more ideas on how to synchronize the separate threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the output from a subprocess to other processes without reading all output at once then here's an implementation of [@abarnert's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19387814/4279) to loop over `p1.stdout` that achieves it:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# start subprocesses
p1 = Popen(cmd1, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
p2 = Popen(cmd2, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1)
p3 = Popen(cmd3, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1)

# "tee" the data
for line in iter(p1.stdout.readline, b''): # assume line-oriented data
    p2.stdin.write(line)
    p3.stdin.write(line)

# clean up
for pipe in [p1.stdout, p2.stdin, p3.stdin]:
    pipe.close()
for proc in [p1, p2, p3]:
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: Except that if you can't be sure that `p2` or `p3` will never block or take too long to service the pipe, this will deadlock. To do this safely, you really need either `select` or three threads.

Comment: @abarnert: I don't see how you could get a deadlock here unless the processes behave pathologically in that case neither `select` nor threads would help. You might be confusing it with the case when you read/write multiple pipes from the *same* process (it is easy to deadlock in this case).

Comment: If `p2` just doesn't read from its pipe, your `p2.stdin.write` will block until it's ready. That means `p3` won't get its data because `p2` isn't ready. And `p1` will just keep spewing out data until it fills up the pipe. You can fix both of those problems (at the cost of buffering up unbounded amounts of data, of course) with something like [this](http://pastebin.com/0a3PkhmK).

Comment: @abarnert: It is the pathological (and uninteresting) behaviour I've referred to: `select` or threads can't force `p2` to read the data.

Comment: But they can allow `p1` and `p3` to proceed even if `p2` blocks for a while.